# Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 fonts & colors dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Do the characters in the preview box mean anything?

[image]

Have wracked my brains and probably missed the obvious, or I'm a bit daft and its something I should already know!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the characters which are very often confused. For instance, in some typefaces `I` looks very similar to `l` or to `1`. The same is for `B` and `8`, `0`, and `O`.

This dialog allows you to see how "different" these glyphs are.

See [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000969.html) by Jeff Atwood for a comprehensive comparison of various fixed-width fonts. [This](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000157.html) is basically the same, but it's from pre-Vista era.

Comment: Would be nice to have {} and () as well. Many typefaces only have a subtle difference between brackets and curly brackets.

Comment: Ah, of course, and as suspected I did miss the obvious! Thanks. (but I was secretly hoping that there was something more clever/sinister in it)

Comment: Other characters that could be included are ->*, to check they're centered in height.